# Use boost::mutex with MFC threads (AfxBeginThread)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, mutex, boost-thread

Can you use the boost::mutex libraries to protect a critical section of code when you are *not* using boost::thread but instead using the MFC threading capability via AfxBeginThread?  If so, are there any problems with doing this?

Answer (score 1):

A (real) thread is a (real) thread.

Boost makes no special assumptions about the fact that a thread has been created directly (Windows API) or via Boost.

Short answer:

No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There is no problem since both are using the Win32 API behind the scenes.

Comment: "Boost is _using the Win32 API behind the scenes_" That was my first reaction, but technically this is not strictly sufficient: you must check that Boost does not keeps a list of threads created via Boost somewhere just to forbid the use of `boost::mutex` in a thread not created with Boost! (Boost does not do that, indeed.)